# json data in loop of angular view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

How to call this json data in loop of angular view(ng-repeat)...

Here is my json
         {
         "customers": [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "LoadTestName1",
            "lastName": "LoadTestLN1",
            "emailAddress": "loadtest1@gmail.com"
           },
           {
              "id": 2,
              "firstName": "LoadTestName2",
              "lastName": "LoadTestLN2",
              "emailAddress": "loadt"
              }
               ]
               }

Comment: Sorry, but your question shows that you did nothing to solve this on your own. Please don't let users do your work before even trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

in the controller: `$scope.var1 = yourJson;`

in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in var1.customers">
 {{item.firstName}} ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip the outer braces:

$scope.customers = [ { "id": 1, "firstName": "LoadTestName1",                      "lastName": "LoadTestLN1", "emailAddress": "loadtest1@gmail.com" }, { "id": 2, "firstName": "LoadTestName2", "lastName": "LoadTestLN2", "emailAddress": "loadt" } ];

```
ng-repeat="customer in customers">
  <div>{{customer.firstName}}</div>
</div>
```